# How do I convert a sitemap.xml to an html fragment?

Tags: jekyll

I am using the jekyll-sitemap plugin (https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap) to generate a sitemap.xml file. I would like to use SlickMap CSS (https://www.astuteo.com/slickmap/) or (https://github.com/tdreyno/compass-slickmap) to style this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Just create a sitemap.html page to render your sitemap as slickmap html pattern.

https://github.com/tdreyno/compass-slickmap seems to be dead (last commit 2011).